# ASP.NET - Disabling validators in a gridview using javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, gridview, validation

Further to my question on disabling validators using javascript - [Disable ASP.NET validators with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400346/disable-asp-net-validators-with-javascript) ...

Does anyone know how to pass through a gridview in javascript to dynamically disable the validators on each row. I now understand that I'll need to use ValidatorEnable(validatorControl, false) to disable each validator but how do I discover the validators in the first place?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to drill down through the gridview and select the individual validators that way.

An excellent example of accessing a gridview with javascript can be found [here](http://www.netomatix.com/development/gridviewclientsideaccess.aspx)