# disable asp.net validator using jquery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I am trying to disable validators using jquery.

I have already looked 
[Disable ASP.NET validators with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400346/disable-asp-net-validators-with-javascript)
and couple of others doing the same.

It seems ot be working but its breaking.

My code:

```
$('.c_MyValdiators').each(function() {

    var x = $(this).attr('id');
    var y = document.getElementById(x);
    ValidatorEnable(y[0], false);
});
```

I get Error: 
*val is undefined
[Break on this error] val.enabled = (enable != false);\r\n*

Alternatively if I use

```
$('.c_MyValdiators').each(function() {
    ValidatorEnable($(this), false); OR ValidatorEnable($(this[0]), false);
  });
```

I get Error:

*val.style is undefined
[Break on this error] val.style.visibility = val.isvalid ? "hidden" : "visible";\r\n*

Any idea or suggestions?

Comment: As a basic troublehooting tip, you may first want to see what is being passed to your function.  What does x or y return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I beleive that ValidatorEnable takes the ASP.net ID rather that the ClientID produced by ASP.net.  You will also need to make the validation conditional in the CodeBehind.

here is an example:

Of particular use is to be able to enable or disable validators. If you have validation that you want active only in certain scenarios, you may need to change the activation on both server and client, or you will find that the user cannot submit the page.

Here is the previous example with a field that should only be validated when a check box is unchecked:

```
public class Conditional : Page {
    public HtmlInputCheckBox chkSameAs;
    public RequiredFieldValidator rfvalShipAddress;
    public override void Validate() {
        bool enableShip = !chkSameAs.Checked;
        rfvalShipAddress.Enabled = enableShip;
        base.Validate();
    }
}
```

Here is the client-side equivalent:

```
<input type=checkbox runat=server id=chkSameAs 
   onclick="OnChangeSameAs();" >Same as Billing<br>
<script language=javascript>
function OnChangeSameAs() {
    var enableShip = !event.srcElement.status;
    ValidatorEnable(rfvalShipAddress, enableShip);
}
</script>
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The MSDN link is good for future reference. I dont have any validate() to override since I m in ascx file. 
I just got it working after so many tries though using:
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')), true);

There is one more problem, Since this just enabling/disabling on the client side, how can I disable my validators as such they are disabled when the page postbacks? 
any ideas?

Comment: you may want to just create a CustomValidator with a custom clientside script that checks based on a condition.  The link i posted above shows how to do this as well

Answer (score 6):

I just stumbled upon your Question [a year later].
I too wanted to disable all validators on a page using JQuery here is how I handled it.

```
$('span[evaluationfunction]').each(function(){ValidatorEnable(this,false);});
```

I look for each span on the page that has the evaluatefunction attribute then call ValidatorEnabled for each one of them.

I think the $('this') part of your code is what was causing the hickup.

Answer (score 2):

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')), true);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got another solution, which is to use the 'enabled' property of the span tag for the validator. I had different divs on a form that would show or hide so I needed to disable the validation for the fields inside the hidden div. This solution turns off validation without firing them.

If you have a set of RequiredFieldvalidator controls that all contain a common string that you can use to grab them the jquery is this:

```
$("[id*='CommonString']").each(function() {
    this.enabled = false;   // Disable Validation
});

or

$("[id*='CommonString']").each(function() {
    this.enabled = true;    // Enable Validation
});
```

Hope this helps.

John

Answer (score 1):

I'm just running into the same problem, thanks to the other answers, as it helped uncover the problem, but they haven't gone into detail why.

I believe it is due to that ValidatorEnable() expects a DOM object (i.e. the validation control object) opposed to an ID.

$(selector).each() sets "this" to the DOM element being currently iterated over i.e. quoted from the jquery documentation:

> "More importantly, the callback is fired in the context of the current
>   DOM element, so the keyword this refers to the element." - http://api.jquery.com/each/

Therefore you **do not** need to do: `document.getElementById($(this).attr('id')`

And instead `ValidatorEnable(this, true);` is fine.

<del>Interestingly, Russ's answer mentioned needing to disable server side validation as well, which does make sense - but I didn't need to do this (which is concerning!).</del>

Scrap my previous comment, it is because I had my control disabled server-side previously.

Answer (score 0):

The ValidatorEnable function takes an object as the 1st parameter and not a string of the id of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to handle this.

Add a new class to the Validation control.

Then look for that class with jquery and disable the control.

Example :

```
if (storageOnly == 1)
   {
        $('#tblAssignment tr.assdetails').addClass('hidden');

        $('span[evaluationfunction]').each(function ()
        {
            if ($(this).hasClass('assdetail'))
            { ValidatorEnable(this, false); }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $('#tblAssignment tr.assdetails').removeClass('hidden');
    }
```

*** Works like a charm. 
** For you imaginative types,  assdetail == assignment detail.

Here depending on the if condition, I am either hiding  the rows then disabling the validator , or removing hidden class from the rows..

Answer (score 0):

Various ways to this depending on your needs. Some solutions in the following blog posts:

http://imjo.hn/2013/03/28/javascript-disable-hidden-net-validators/

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2008/05/14/How-to-manage-ASP.NET-validation-from-Javascript-with-jQuery.aspx