# Javascript function to disable validation on your page

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

I need a javascript function, which can turn my asp.net validation off on the webpage.
Do anyone have any idea about this.

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400346/disable-asp-net-validators-with-javascript

Answer (score 2):

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025143824/http://geekswithblogs.net/jonasb/archive/2006/08/11/87708.aspx)

```
var myVal = document.getElementById('myValidatorClientID');
ValidatorEnable(myVal, false);
```

This article seems to be useful, too:
http://aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-control-ASP-NET-Validator-Controls-Client-Side-validation-from-JavaScript.aspx