# How to validate it allows only numerics in c# textbox_TextChanged event

Tags: c#-2.0

Based on the drop down selection the text box should be validate in C# textbox_TextChanged event. If drop down selection value is 1 it allows characters and if 2 it allows numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Int32.TryParse` to validate the integer input

Here's a link to an example of its usage
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can add a compare validator to the textbox, in the compare valudator change de operator to check type and in datatype add integer. This control can be enable or disable instead us using a server aide event you can use javascript to enable the validator when necesarry.

Im this question you can find information on how to enable or disable the validator [Disable ASP.NET validators with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400346/disable-asp-net-validators-with-javascript)

You can use jquery to get the value of the dropdown more easy.  If the dropdown is a server side element use in the selector the nameofcontrol.clientid to get the correct name of the control.

Comment: how to validate it allows only alphabets by using compare operator

Comment: Hi if you want to validate only alphabets you may better use a regular expression validator. You have to find or create a validation expression that better fit your requirements.